# VS2010 App builds but won't launch in IE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I had a disk crash the other day and had to restore my development project to a new desktop PC. It is an ASP.NET 3.5 project built in VB.NET. It was running fine on the old computer but when I run it now I get "Page cannot be displayed" error in IE (not very verbose). If I try the localhost URL in Chrome or Firefox it tells me there are too many redirects.

I'm not sure what's going on as nothing has changed with the project other than it is on a different computer. Right now, I'm not even sure where to begin to debug this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: seems like an IIS Default website issue. ensure that the IIS path I set to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot and that there are no other sites there causing issues.

Comment: I believe IIS is setup correctly as I have at least one other application project that runs fine.

Comment: Have you checked to see where are you being redirected using the F12 tools in IE?

Comment: It seems that Windows choked will installing an update. I ran the Windows updates again, and after that, the application launched fine.